# The most common sparse matrix format

Tags: c++, matrix, file-format, sparse-matrix

What is the most common sparse matrix format?

I've read of Harwell Boing format, Yale format and although is not explicitly a sparse matrix format, the SVMLight by Thorsten Joachims which exploit the sparsity.

What should be the simplest to write a exception-safe parser in C++?

Comment: SVMLight is quite easy to parse, but it's not standardized; I've seen files that assume 1-based column indices and zero-based ones. What do you need this for?

Comment: Why down vote? It's a useful question. I know SVMlight is easy to parse but I want to write a parser that works on the most common format rather than spending time and effort for an unused format.

Comment: Do you mean in memory or on disk? Compressed row storage is possibly the most common spare matrix format for a program to work with and is easy to implement and iterate through. As for on disk, well use whatever your source provides, I have had good success with the Matrix Market format as used by the Florida Sparse Matrix Collection

Comment: Again, why do you need this? There are various formats in use in various fields (e.g. SVMlight is popular in machine learning) for either computations or storage. You should write a parser for the format that you expect your application to handle.

Comment: I need to load sparse matrices from file in memory using Eigen SparseMatrix because I have to work with linear system, solvers etc, but I want to give to the user the possibility to cope with famous formats and not inventing a new format, constraining the user to work with conversion scripts or similar...

Comment: @111111: Good, I'm inspecting the Florida Sparse Matrix format, this is one of the answers I wanted.

Comment: @linello I'll make it a propper answer then.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean in memory or on disk?

Compressed row storage is possibly the most common spare matrix format for a program to work with and is easy to implement and iterate through.

As for on disk, well use whatever your source provides, I have had good success with the Matrix Market format as used by the Florida Sparse Matrix Collection

Comment: The matrix market format stores in column major order though, did you have to do some processing to convert to row major?